# Array of string with JSON and custom adapter

Tags: java, android, json

Good morning, i'm retrieving some values from my MySQL database because i want to display them into a ListView with custom adapter. I have this code.

```
            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                ogge = new Ogge();
                json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ogge.title = json.getString("Title");
                ogge.array = new String[] {json.getString("field1"), json.getString("field2"), json.getString("field3"), json.getString("field4"), json.getString("field5"), json.getString("field6")};
                ogge.adapter = Ogge.MY_CUSTOM;     
                list.add(ogge);
            }
```

This for is correct because the values are put in the array in Ogge class. This is the adapter

```
    case Ogge.MY_CUSTOM:
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
        textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(ogge.title));
        textView2.setText(MyJsonClass.DATABASE_FIELD[position]);
        textView3.setText(ogge.array[position]);

        break;
```

The problem is the follow: when i open my app i see only the first and the second value of ogge.array but i want to show all. If i make a for into the adapter to get the value from the array the values are all stored into the array so the array is correct but, then, why i show only the first two values and not all?

Adapter full code

```
public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Ogge> list) {   
        super(context, resource, list);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final Ogge ogge = list.get(position);

        switch(ogge.adapter) {

        case Ogge.MY_CUSTOM:
       view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
        textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(ogge.title));
        textView2.setText(MyJsonClass.DATABASE_FIELD[position]);
        textView3.setText(ogge.array[position]);

        break;
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Comment: post full adapter code

Comment: did you extend ArrayAdaper? or BaseAdapter? what is the value of `lista`

Comment: I extend ArrayAdapter<Ogge>. Sorry, the correct word is list, i pressed for error the "a"

Comment: check size of list in constructor method

Comment: your code has logic error, you not handle that if `ogge.adapter` is not equal with `Ogge.MY_CUSTOM`, so you might get NPE.

Comment: i've already checked before. it's 2.

Comment: so you just see only the first and the second value of ogge when size of list is 2, what you want ?

Comment: I want to show also all the value of ogge.array

Comment: are you sure that you want to use ListView ? did you see expandable list because i think that better for your situation, if you don't want to use expandable list you need extend `BaseAdapter` instead of ArrayAdapter and change value of `getCount` with some of list's item. you need handle that in `getView` too because if you not handle that you get `ArrayIndexOut` as your size is 2